# How can an Attribute enforce inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, constraints

In order to decorate a class with `AttributeUsage`, the decorated class must also inherit from `Attribute`.

Can I enforce a similar constraint with a custom attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that is to use protected attribute, but in that case, you'll force users of your attribute to inherit from your attribute class.

```
abstract class CustomAttribute : Attribute {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    protected sealed class MyTestAttribute : Attribute {}
}

[MyTest]
class DerivedFromYourCustomAttribute : CustomAttribute {
}

[MyTest]
class NotDerivedFromYourCustomAttribute {
}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but `AttributeUsageAttribute` is not a nested type of `System.Attribute`, so it leaves the question - how is that restriction enforced?

Comment: @V0ldek: that is what I was originally wondering; maybe a comment decoration?
However, this does achieve a similar affect. Although, with `MyTestAttribute` restricted to `protected`, cannot find the type decorated with the attribute. I made `MyTestAttribute` public so I could locate the decorated class.

Comment: @V0ldek:: The `AttributeUsageAttribute` receives special treatment by the C# compiler. You cannot do this. You can see its source code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/attributeusageattribute.cs). There is no conspicuous feature. There's only an amusing detail: the  `AttributeUsageAttribute` is applied to itself!

Comment: I find nothing in comments in AttributeUsageAttribute to enforce it

Comment: @Anton_Anpilogov: here in `Attrubute` base class...  `Contract.Requires(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Attribute))`

Comment: @IAbstract: this applies only to the parameter of the `InternalGetCustomAttributes` method and has nothing specific to do with the `AttributeUsageAttribute` class.

Answer (score 3):

The `AttributeUsageAttribute` is apparently a core feature of the language, so this restriction is mandated by the [C# specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/attributes.md#the-attributeusage-attribute):

> A class that is decorated with the `AttributeUsage` attribute must derive from `System.Attribute`, either directly or indirectly. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

That means there's no straightforward way of achieving such a restriction. You can write a custom static analyzer to throw warnings at erroneous usage, or see Anton Anpilogov's answer for a workaround.

Comment: I assume this is the *magic*: `Contract.Requires(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Attribute))`